# Lazy ViewModel property initialization

Tags: c#, initialization, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm developing an application with an IoC container and object composition from compisition root. The goal is to minimize the time of the object construction by defering the initialization of the ViewModel's properties.

As I'm quite new to the world of IoC my initial approach was to just call the `IRepository` right in the constructor and fill the property. But this leads to lots of calls during object composition.

I don't want to create an `Initialize` method because calling this might be forgotten and lead to an invalid object state.

I'm thinking of using `Lazy<>` for a defered initialization like this:

```
readonly Lazy<IEnumerable<Customer>> _lazyCustomers;
public virtual IEnumerable<Customer> Customers => _lazyCustomers.Value;

public ReportViewModel(IReportRepository repository)
{
    _lazyCustomers = new Lazy<IEnumerable<Customer>>(repository.GetCustomers);
}
```

This looks promising, but if the property has a setter I have to come up with an extra field, because I can't set a Lazy's Value:

```
<IEnumerable<Customer> _customers;
readonly Lazy<IEnumerable<Customer>> _lazyCustomers;
public virtual IEnumerable<Customer> Customers {
    get { return _customers ?? (_customers = _lazyCustomers.Value); }
    set { _customer = value; }
}
```

This look looks overcomplicated from my perspective. I could get rid of the `Lazy<>` alltogether and directly call the `IReportRepository` in the property's getter.

What's a good pattern for property initialization (after object construction)? Is this too complicated and should I stick with an `Initialize` method?

Comment: Why not just initialise the customers list to an empty list.

Comment: The question here is how and when to load the customers from the repository.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have here has nothing to do with IOC. You shouldn't be making calls like GetCustomers in your constructor.

If you want to cache your customers (this will load the customers from the repository on the first call and then use the private variable thereafter) you could do something like:

```
    private IEnumerable<Customer> _customers;
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers {
        get { 
             if (_customers == null) 
             {
                _customers = _customerRepository.GetCustomers();
             }
             return _customers; 
        }
    }

   public AddCustomer(Customer customer) {
             if (_customers == null) 
             {
                _customers = _customerRepository.GetCustomers();
             }
             _cusomers.Add(customer);   
   }
```

Comment: OK. That is what I was thinking. But isn't this awkward with `null` values? What if someone sets `viewModel.Customers = null`. The next call to the property's setter will reinitialize the property.

Comment: Check out my changes above. You could do something like this.  And then add a save changes function to write changes back to the repository. Although your outer class in this case referred to a report which generally wouldn't be making changes to existing data....

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think I'm just adding an additional null check in the property's setter to make sure the value is always valid:`if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));`